# fire bug says HierarchyRequestError: Node cannot be inserted at the specified point in the hierarchy

Tags: javascript, html

```
    document.getElementById('customerName').onchange =function(){
        if( document.getElementById('customerName').value == 0){
            document.getElementById('customer').removeAttribute('readonly','readonly');
            var textArea = document.createElement('textarea');
            textArea.setAttribute('name','address');
            textArea.setAttribute('class','form-control');
            var tr = document.createElement('tr');
            var td = document.createElement('td');
            var text = document.createTextNode('العنوان');
            td.appendChild(text);
            tr.appendChild(td);
            td = document.createElement('td');
            td.appendChild(textArea);
            tr.appendChild(tr);
            document.getElementById('customeBody').appendChild(tr);


        }
```

Trying to append 2 (td)s one with only text and the other with text area but this error appears HierarchyRequestError: Node cannot be inserted at the specified point in the hierarchy

Comment: `tr.appendChild(tr);` <- wondering what does this do?

Comment: dame man thanx LOLZ/ @SalmanA